# Django admin site: how to include conditional fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I wonder if is it possible to add some conditional fields in django.
Say I have a category model which has an ID, name and description fields.
What I would like is to add a many-to-many field in my Product model that links it with the Category ID model... and as a helping reference show what the name of that Category would be.
I know I could just link it to the category name, but my real scenario is a bit more complex and I would really need to display a second field based on the selection in another !

Many thanks!

Comment: I forgot to explain that I need this to happen in the ADMIN !

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Daniel's answer: If you just want to customize the representation of the objects in a `ModelChoiceField` (and not change it in general what you would do with the `__unicode__` method): The field class has method `label_from_instance`, which returns by default the object's unicode value, but you can override it as you like:

```
class CategoryChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return "%s %s" % obj.pk, obj.name
```

Comment: does this work in the admin site? that's where I need this info to be displayed... I need some fields to be filled automatically based on the value of some other fields. thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's not a conditional field. If I understand you correctly, all you really need is to customise the display of the related item, so that it shows the `name` field rather than the raw ID. Luckily, that is what Django will do by default if you define a `__unicode__` method on the Category model, which returns the value you want to display instead of the ID.

Comment: umh... Im not sure I explained myself correctly: I need this to happen in the admin site. Im still at the very beginning of my django experience, but I thinh the __unicode__ method is to use in templates and other documents but not in the admin panel. THANSK

Comment: No, that works wherever you have a foreign key, including the admin site.